# GAN Produces Error for 3D Images saying the channels are incorrect

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I am receiving the following error with the below code. I am working with a GAN. I successfully trained it to produce grayscale images and now I changed it to make 3D images. I added a third dimension in the generator and now have this error. Any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/user/5EB3-54BF/gan3.py", line 84, in <module>
    generator = make_generator_model()
  File "/media/user/5EB3-54BF/gan3.py", line 63, in make_generator_model
    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/trackable/base.py", line 205, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/conv2d_transpose.py", line 205, in build
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Inputs should have rank 4. Received input_shape=(None, 14, 14, 3, 512).


def make_generator_model():
        model = tf.keras.Sequential() #make 14
        model.add(layers.Dense(14*14*3*512, use_bias=False, input_shape=(300,))) #ADD MORE NOISE!!!!!!!
        model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

        model.add(layers.Reshape((14, 14, 3, 512)))
        assert model.output_shape == (None, 14, 14, 3, 512)  # Note: None is the batch size

        model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
        assert model.output_shape == (None, 14, 14, 3, 256)
        model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

        model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
        assert model.output_shape == (None, 28, 28, 3, 128)
        model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
        
        #additional layer added here
        model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
        assert model.output_shape == (None, 56, 56, 3, 64)
        model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

        model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
        assert model.output_shape == (None, 112, 112, 3)

        return model
```

Answer (score 0):

`Conv2DTranspose` is not defined for 5D vectors (aka rank 5)... what about using [Conv3DTranspose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv3DTranspose)?